# How can I use xdmp:value dynamically?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to combine xdmp:value with cts:contains in a single function, where the value passed to xdmp:value is dynamic. I'm fairly new to functional programming, so my understanding may be very flawed here.

This is a working example that places the dynamic parameter in cts:contains instead that should clarify my intent:

```
declare functional local:matchRegion($region as xs:string, $country as xs:string?)
as xs:boolean
{
  let $in-country := '/country[name-variants/variant = $country]/regions/name-variants/variants'
  let $anywhere := '/country/regions/region/name-variants/variant'

  let $found := cts:contains(?, $region)
  return
    if ($country)
      then ($found(xdmp:value($in-country)))
      else ($found(xdmp:value($anywhere)))
};

local:matchRegion("ohio","usa") (: returns true :)
```

I'm trying to front-load the call to xdmp:value.

Here is what I've tried:
1) With the arrow operator

```
declare functional local:matchRegion($region as xs:string, $country as xs:string?)
as xs:boolean
{
  let $in-country := '/country[name-variants/variant = $country]/regions/name-variants/variants'
  let $anywhere := '/country/regions/region/name-variants/variant'

  let $found := xdmp:value(?) => cts:contains($region) 
  return
    if ($country)
      then ($found($in-country))
      else ($found($anywhere))
};
local:matchRegion("ohio","usa") (: XDMP-XMLFUNC... Functions cannot be used in the content of an element constructor :)
```

2) With the simple map operator:

```
declare functional local:matchRegion($region as xs:string, $country as xs:string?)
as xs:boolean
{
  let $in-country := '/country[name-variants/variant = $country]/regions/name-variants/variants'
  let $anywhere := '/country/regions/region/name-variants/variant'

  let $found := xdmp:value(?) ! cts:contains(?,$region) 
  return
    if ($country)
      then ($found($in-country))
      else ($found($anywhere))
};
local:matchRegion("ohio","usa") (: returns false :)
```

3) With an anonymous function:

```
declare functional local:matchRegion($region as xs:string, $country as xs:string?)
as xs:boolean
{
  let $in-country := '/country[name-variants/variant = $country]/regions/name-variants/variants'
  let $anywhere := '/country/regions/region/name-variants/variant'

  let $a := function($x,$y){cts:contains(xdmp:value($x),$y)}
  let $found := $a(?,$region) 
  return
    if ($country)
      then ($found($in-country))
      else ($found($anywhere))
};
local:matchRegion("ohio","usa") (: returns false :)
```

I have functions to write with similar intent to matchRegion which will have many more conditions involved and many more xpath expressions; I'm trying to leverage dynamic calls to keep the syntax readable and xdmp:value to avoid unnecessary evaluations of xpaths. How can I do this? Also, why do the latter two implementations return false? Lastly, I don't think cts:contains is going to be doing anything special for me, in that I need exact matches. I'm quite new to all this so please let me know if there is a better function to call.

Thank you

UPDATE:
Here is an example of an xml file I'd query:

```
<country>
  <name>Canada</name>
  <name-variants>
    <variant>canada</variant>
  </name-variants>
  <regions>
    <region>
      <name>Manitoba</name>
      <name-variants>
        <variant>manitoba</variant>
        <variant>province of manitoba</variant>
      </name-variants>
    </region>
  </regions>
</country>
```

Comment: I am confused why you think you need xdmp:value, or even cts:contains. Can you explain in plain English what you are trying to do? It looks like all you need is to confirm whether a region falls into a country, but that would be just one static XPath with two variables, without the need to xdmp:value nor cts:contains..

Comment: @grtjn Firstly, the country may not be supplied, so I can't always limit the search for the region within one country. The second xpath allows for this possibility, where the region is recognized anywhere in the world. Secondly, I have another function to write which has many more such possible inputs - finding a city where an enclosing region and country may or may not be supplied. xdmp:value lets me define the xpaths as strings. This has the advantage of letting me name the scope of the xpath and delay evaluation.

Comment: @grtjn I agree that cts:contains may not be useful, given that I'm not looking to do stemming. I haven't looked into what else it brings to the table, compared to fn:contains. I'm very fresh to marklogic and xquery

Comment: @grtjn I read some more on the indexing that is done by default in marklogic, and I understand now what you meant. I can use a straight xpath expression without any contains check. Still, I'd like to understand how I could have done what I intended for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tripped over a couple of snags in your attempts, aside from various large typos in your code that you shared above. Fiona already mentioned that 'functional' really needs to be `function`, and there are mistakes in your xpaths too, like missing `/region` and `/variant`.

First off, the use of ? to create a partial function is very uncommon. To be honest, I have not seen it being used before in XQuery, and it looks like it is MarkLogic specific. XQuery 3 anonymous functions should work equally well, and might make it easier to read for others.

The first attempt is the most straight-forward approach of your attempts. No surprise it works, although it looks unnecessary complex. You can just put the XPaths in place, without xdmp:value. They only get evaluated if the code reaches them. The if can make sure only the right XPath is evaluated.

The second attempt with the arrow operator tries to feed a partial function as first argument into cts:contains, but cts:contains is not waiting with execution, so it tries to evaluate the first argument immediately, and then bailing out because it cannot convert the partial function to a text or element node to compare against.

The third attempt has two partial functions, but it is not feeding the first into the latter. Instead the ! operator simply replaces the first with the latter. You end up passing in the XPaths as strings into cts:contains, and the XPaths as strings won't match the region. cts:contains silently converts atomic values into text nodes.

The fourth attempt with the anonymous function still uses the ? argument on top, which looks a little bit silly, because you could also work with the anonymous function directly. The reason why it fails is rather subtle though. It looks like the value of $country is not carried along, or at least not properly. Replacing `$country` with its literal value in the XPath, which you can do on the spot since it is a string expression anyhow, will get you a `true`.

Personally, I would avoid all of it, and rather use hard-coded XPaths instead. Or, if you need to be able to scale this to many regions: use cts:search with cts:queries instead. Here a gist which lists your attempts, and a few from me:

https://gist.github.com/grtjn/d7bd4b65e9b616bf62b0a5196bc006a2

HTH!

Comment: Yeah lots of typos. Sorry. Thanks for the explanations. Part of my motivation for this post is understanding how partial functions work and all this new syntax (new for me, at least). I experimented a bit with function calls and if I define the same xpath repeatedly without quotes, execution time slows noticeably. That's why I wanted to use xdmp:value. I have thousands of regions in hundreds of countries. Thank you for the extra function calls. Very nice to see other ways to do it.

Comment: Note: partial function application really is an XQuery 3 feature. MarkLogic support some of them, including this one: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_65246

Comment: Giving @grtjn because the answer is more educational.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, FaraBara:**

Please try below XQuery function.

```
declare function local:matchOrNot( $region as xs:string, 
                                   $country as xs:string)
as xs:boolean
{
  some $i in doc()/country/descendant-or-self::*[contains(., $country)]
  satisfies $i/regions/region/descendant-or-self::*[contains(., $region)]
};

local:matchOrNot("new york", "usa");
```

You can test few documents, e.g:
[image]

> You should expect below results:

```
local:matchOrNot("new york", "usa");  => true
local:matchOrNot("new york", "USA");  => true
local:matchOrNot("New York", "USA");  => true
local:matchOrNot("New York", "usa"); => true
local:matchOrNot("New York", "Canada");  => false
Any combination of "New York" and "Canada" throws back "false"
```

Comment: Thank you for offering this alternative solution. If you can, please elaborate on the errors you've seen in my versions of the function. Also, I'm finding that your solution is up to 30x slower than mine, when the country is not given, and 20x slower even if the country is given. My first function works exactly as expected, so that is not logically flawed. I'm still struggling to understand why other iterations of the function fail.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, FaraBara:**

[image]

1. It is `declare function` not `declare functional`
2. Returned sequence is `false` which is **false** result
3. Due to xpath logic issue, your queries become '`lazy`', checking fewer conditions.

> Speaking of execution time:  **PT0.0000922S** **<** **PT0.0002321S**

[image]

Comment: Yeah a lot of typos. I wasn't on the same computer on which I was developing when I wrote this question. For the laziness, I want fewer conditions to be checked when there is no country. Why is that a problem? For the performance, when I compare my working query with yours using my data set, which has several thousand regions, mine is 20 - 30x faster. I'm guessing this is because of the indexes in marklogic which your query might not take advantage of. That is probably because yours checks many more nodes than mine would, being more vague.